# I'm looking for a component / circuit that distinguishes between eight states

Tags: counter, pspice

I use *PSpice For TI2020*, so I don't have a pre-assembled ring counter in the library. I'm looking for a way of setting a specific output to *High* from eight states that come from 3 flip-flops (up counter). I made a few pictures for illustration. I just don't know how to build a composition of logic gates. I don't expect you to completely solve this; I just need a thought.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or spoken as a programmer (pseudocode C#):

```
private byte find_out()
    {
        if (a8Z[0] && !a8Z[1] && !a8Z[2])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (!a8Z[0] && a8Z[1] && !a8Z[2])
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (a8Z[0] && a8Z[1] && !a8Z[2])
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else if (!a8Z[0] && !a8Z[1] && a8Z[2])
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else if (a8Z[0] && !a8Z[1] && a8Z[2])
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else if (!a8Z[0] && a8Z[1] && a8Z[2])
        {
            return 6;
        }
        else if (a8Z[0] && a8Z[1] && a8Z[2])
        {
            return 7;
        }
        else
        {
            return 255;
        } // If I got all of the above lines of code correctly, this should never occur. 
    }
```

Comment: You’ve written the logic already! The logic arrangement is called a ‘decoder’. More specifically you want a 3 to 8 decoder. The only change to your logic is the output would be 8 booleans rather than an enumerated value.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks for the word. How is it listed in PSpice? If I enter "decoder" in the search, nothing comes up.

Comment: _You've written the logic already!_ That's right, Based on the code, I could do something like this: https://i1.wp.com/www.electroniclinic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/3-to-8-line-decoder-logic-diagram.png?ssl=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking about is called a "decoder" and in this case a "3-to-8" decoder.

The decoder takes a 3 bit binary input and outputs a single line on the output corresponding to the input.

Comment: Thanks for the word. How is it listed in PSpice? If I enter "decoder" in the search, nothing comes up.

Comment: PSpice is primarily an ANALOG simulator.  Its support for digital devices is quite limited.  Your circuit is a digital one, why don't you use a digital logic simulator instead?

Comment: Can you say one?

Comment: Microcap by [Spectrum-Soft](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm) is now free and it does both analog and digital simulations. Grab it while you can. There are some tutorials available on YT. Also consult the _Newsletters_ section on Spectrum's website, they contain a ton of know-how. And the user guide (PDF) is also great. If images are broken on a page, visit the site via the WayBackMachine.